# Angular 2 new app stuck at "Loading..."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn Angular 2 now and am trying my first Hello World app but it is just stuck at "Loading..." after I hit `npm start`

I'm on Windows 10 and ran this on all my Browsers (Chrome, Edge and IE) but ran into the same error.

I haven't found an answer that helps me so far here so please help!!

**index.html**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My First Angular App</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content ="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){console.error(err);});
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...
    </my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>',
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app : 'ScriptsApp', // 'dist',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: { main: './boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
            rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start" : "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34"
  }
}
```

All of these have been compiled into js files. I'm not receiving any error messages, the page is just staying at "Loading..."

Comment: What is the error you see when you push F12?

Comment: I would say that you are missing angular library itself. You are not loading script files with angular.

Comment: Which tutorial? I tried this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html and it worked on the spot.

Comment: I've install all the node_modules with a separate `package.json` file. I also have `tsconfig.json` and `systemjs.config.js`

Comment: @dparsons I got the follow 404s in console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2Reflect.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/ScriptsApp/boot.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:16 ZoneAwareError
(anonymous) @ localhost/:16
styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Error is self explanatory - it can't load the libraries. Try figuring out where the HTML file is located and what path leads to the imports you are loading

Comment: Like the error says, the app can't load 2Reflect or boot.js.  You haven't provided enough information here for me to pinpoint the problem, but it looks like it is either a systemjs.config problem, or you are missing some packages.

Comment: I did some research and could not find anything about installing those modules. Is there something I'm missing? I edited the post with my `systemjs.config.js` and `packages.json` files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to resolve the 404. You have told SystemJS that your boot script is at ScriptsApp/boot.js however it is telling you that it can't find it.  That is likely your problem.